# Links stop working after scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my website have a top header that can move around with the smooth scroll, the smooth scroll works but once I have the top header move around with the smooth scroll the links stop working!

HTML:

```
<div class="Bob">
<nav class="nav1">

<a href="file:///Users/tc10077403/Desktop/Project%206/Project6.html" style="font-size: 50px;">Home Page</a>

<a href="file:///Users/tc10077403/Desktop/Project%206/Games.html" style="font-size: 50px;">Games</a>

<a href="file:///Users/tc10077403/Desktop/Project%206/History.html" style="font-size: 50px;">History</a>

<a href="file:///Users/tc10077403/Desktop/Project%206/Content.html" style="font-size: 50px;">Features</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Bob{
position: fixed;
}
.nav1{
text-align: center;
margin-left: 350px;
background-color: #333333;
}
```

Other stuff:

```
#home { 
  background: url(background.jpeg) 50% 0 repeat none; min-height: 1000px; 
  height: 1000px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1920px; 
  position: relative; 
}

#home article { 
  height: 458px; 
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center; 
  top: 150px; 
  width: 100%; 
}

#about { 
  background: url(Background-2.png) 50% 0 repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px; 
  height: 1000px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1920px; 
  position: relative; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#about article { 
  height: 458px; 
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center; 
  top: 150px; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: As in "header" i mean Menu

Comment: Its most likely a JS issue because HTML looks fine, can you create a jsFiddle reproducing your problem ? Also what is the smooth scroll library you are using ?

Comment: agree with @Pogrindis this looks fine; maybe you should put some html part as well.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your code is fine. why not move your files in the same folder and remove file:///Users/tc10077403/Desktop/Project%206/

Answer (score 0):

Might you possibly have a div or other DOM element blocking the nav on scroll?

Test this: try to tab to the links (make sure you haven't set your outline to none) and hit ENTER to engage the link. If that works then it may be under another DOM element.

Please post a link that we could look at.

Comment: I've been told that my parallax scrolling is blocking the anchor tag... And i have absolutely no clue what that means.

Comment: Sounds like your content that moves in when you scroll is laying over top.  One way to fix would be to give the nav container a higher z-index.